# Keep same css attribute with menu links on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, css, menu, toggle

I have three text links grouped together inside div:  "English"  "Spanish"  "French"

I need English to be css active when first loading the website, which works perfect. When I click on Spanish or French, the css active moves to the new active link.  Everything works great, but when I change pages, the active css goes back to English even though its still Spanish or French.

How do I stop losing the active css link?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tab").click(function() {
    $(".tab").css("color", "#000");
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
  });
});
```

```css
.transWRAP {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}

.tab {
  color: #000;
  font-size: .8em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  -webkit-transition: color.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color.3s ease-out;
  transition: color.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: border-bottom.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: border-bottom.3s ease-out;
  transition: border-bottom.3s ease-out;
}

.tab:hover {
  color: red;
}

#tab1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transWRAP">
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab1" onclick="doGTranslate('en|en');return false;" title="English" class="nturl">English</a>
  <div class="blmp">&#183;</div>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab2" onclick="doGTranslate('en|es');return false;" title="Spanish" class="nturl">Spanish</a>
  <div class="blmp">&#183;</div>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab3" onclick="doGTranslate('en|fr');return false;" title="French" class="nturl">French</a>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tab").click(function() {
    $(".tab").css("color", "#FFF");
    $(this).css("color", "#FFCC05");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="transWRAP">
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab1" onclick="doGTranslate('en|en');return false;" title="English" class="nturl">English</a>
  <div class="blmp">&#183;</div>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab2" onclick="doGTranslate('en|es');return false;" title="Spanish" class="nturl">Spanish</a>
  <div class="blmp">&#183;</div>
  <a href="#" class="tab" id="tab3" onclick="doGTranslate('en|fr');return false;" title="French" class="nturl">French</a>
</div>
```

```css
.transWRAP {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}

.tab {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: .8em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  -webkit-transition: color.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color.3s ease-out;
  transition: color.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: border-bottom.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: border-bottom.3s ease-out;
  transition: border-bottom.3s ease-out;
}

.tab:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FFCC05;
  color: #FFCC05;
}

#tab1 {
  color: #FFCC05;
}
```

```
$(function() {
  $(".tab").click(function() {
    $(".tab").css("color", "#FFF");
    $(this).css("color", "#FFCC05");
  });
});
```

Comment: I guess the question needs more description. could you please elaborate more what is `doGTranslate`?

Comment: I'm translating the website.

Comment: I need a standard menu toggle css with active.  But I need to keep the active css on all the pages

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)